# Deployed .war file does not open in Weblogic Server

Tags: deployment, web, weblogic, war

I deployed a simple web application (.war file) on Weblogic Server. The application consists of a simple servlet. I created the .war file using the command "jar cf ../mywebapp.war *".
The .war file was deployed fine, but when I try to access the servlet "localhost:7001/mywebapp" it gives a "Error 403--Forbidden ".

Any answers? I apologize if the question is too vague. I am new to web application development.

Thanks,

Comment: It might be possible that your application is in fact returning a HTTP 403. Is the code yours or have someone else handed it to you?

Comment: what is the mapping of your servlet to the URI?  That would have an impact.  WebLogic has a context root setting that you can change, but by default it will be the name of your WAR.  You would have to add /myServletName to the URI most likely.

Comment: @Viccari The code is mine. Its a very simple 'HelloWorld' type of application.

Comment: @JeffWest The context-root in the weblogic.xml is same as what I am using (/mywebapp). Adding the servlet name (/mywebapp/NewServlet) gives resource not found error! (Error 404--Not Found)

Comment: The application works fine if I deploy it as an open deployment by specifying the folder path to the 'web' folder while installing in the WLS. But it does not work if I use the .war file!

Comment: Please post the servlet code, web.xml and weblogic.xml if applicable.